# Where is the rc.boot script file in AIX? Could I access & modify it under the running environment?

Tags: unix, aix, boot

I want to pick up the rc.boot script file & modify something in AIX system.
How to find it out? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **not** to modify the rc.boot script on AIX.

1. Not very many services are started at that point in the boot process - very easy to introduce something that may result in the system not fully booting.
2. May be replaced by updates from IBM without warning - thus wiping out your changes.

Follow the method from [comp.unix.aix](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/aix-faq/part1/section-59.html#b) . This set-up or something similar to it has been used at all the AIX shops I have worked at over the last 20 years. I currently use this on 50+ servers (except it is called `rc.server` instead of `rc.local`). Placing it in the `/etc/inittab` as illustrated (after `rc.nfs`) ensures that NFS services are up and running when your script(s) are run.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I Googled `rc.boot` and the *first* result was [documentation from IBM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.files/doc/aixfiles/rc.boot.htm).

It is located at `/sbin/rc.boot`.